# Why doesn't LeafletJS complete the conversion when re-projecting to Spherical Mercator?

Tags: leaflet, coordinate-system, mapbox

When I use the Mapbox Leaflet pre-packaged Projection class SphericalMercator to project a lat/long coordinate into EPSG:3857 I have to multiply the result Leaflet provides by the earth's radius.

```
var latlng = L.latLng(45, -120);
var sphericalMercator = L.Projection.SphericalMercator.project(latlng);
```

The following is what Leaflet returns:

```
sperhicalMercator.x => -2.0943951023931953
sphericalMercator.y => 0.8813735870195429
```

But the actual answer is `(-13358338.8952, 5621521.48619)`, which I got by multiplying the results returned by Leaflet by 6,378,137 (earth's radius in meters).

```
var actualAnswerX = sphericalMercator.x * 6378137;
var actualAnswerY = sphericalMercator.y * 6378137;
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed [in Leaflet after the 0.7.2 release](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/87520df2e22594ed3f537f12be87a0fdddc9b7b0).

Comment: fix is definitely there [now](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/projection/Projection.SphericalMercator.js#L15), but it doesn't look like it made it into 0.7.3.